# My code doesn't load (stuck at do/while loop?)

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while, dice

I've been trying to make "a program" that basically keeps "throwing dice" (randomize the value) until you get snake eyes, and when you do it's supposed to show how many times the dice were thrown. However, it doesn't load. What did I do wrong?

```
var countRolls = 0;
do {
var die1 = (Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
var die2 = (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
++countRolls;
} while (die1 != 1 || die2 != 1);
console.log(countRolls);
```

I've tried opening it in Chrome/Firefox and it'll just load forever, and I won't be able to open the console. Tried it in JSFiddle, and it became unresponsive.

Comment: How are you trying to load it?

Comment: Oh, right, I've tried opening it in Chrome/Firefox and it'll just say its loading endlessly, and I won't be able to open the console. Tried it in JSFiddle, and it'll become unresponsive

Comment: Try logging the values of `die1` and `die2` each time through the loop, I think you'll see why.

Comment: `Math.random()` doesn't return a whole number.  So, it's very unlikely that this will ever return 1.  So, you're in an infinite loop!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Math.random()` returns a **double**, the chance is almost 0% for die1 and die2 to both be 1

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know it was a double. Math.floor() did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Your loop will never end because you add one to the random function and the stop condition is just testing for not 1 but this will not happen.

Add `console.log(die1,die2);` to your `do {}`